# How can I tell TypeScript a string is one of the members of a union literal?

Tags: typescript

I have an array of string produced from an array of objects I mapped over. I now want to call findIndex with a string (current pathname to be specific) like this:

```
const arrayFromSlugs = guides.map((guide) => {
    return guide.slug
})

function getIndex(pathname: string) {
    return arrayFromSlugs.findIndex(pathname)
    
}
```

but am getting the following TypeScript scream on the findIndex call:

*Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: "getting-started" | "sending-messages" | "embeds" | "buttons" | "links" | "select-menus" | "use-instance" | "custom-adapters", index: number, obj: ("getting-started" | ... 6 more ... | "custom-adapters")[]) => unknown'.ts(2345)*

Comment: Because you're using `findIndex` wrong: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex

Comment: findIndex requires a predicate, use `indexOf` instead. (which will then lead you to the issue that the type is not right, at which point `arrayFromSlugs as string[]` is ok in my view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, the problem is likely just that you're using `findIndex` when you should be using `indexOf`.

However, you can still encounter a similar problem with typing when using `indexOf`, for example:

```
type Slug = 'one'|'two';
type Guide = { slug: Slug };

const guide1: Guide = { slug: 'one'};
const guide2: Guide = { slug: 'two'};

const guides: Guide[] = [guide1, guide2];

const arrayFromSlugs = guides.map(guide => guide.slug);

function getIndex(pathname: string) {
  return arrayFromSlugs.indexOf(pathname)
  //                            ^^^ 
  // Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Slug'.

}
```

To get around this, you would create a [user defined type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) to verify that you're `pathname` is actually of the expected type. For example:

```
function isSlug(value: string): value is Slug {
  return value === "one" || value === "two";
}

function getIndex(pathname: string) {
  return isSlug(pathname) ? arrayFromSlugs.indexOf(pathname) : -1;
}
```

In this simple example, we can easily check if the `pathname` is one of the two strings allowed for the `Slug` type, but what about if `Slug` had many allowed values? In that case, I would do something a bit more dynamic:

```
const SlugValues = {
  one: 'one', 
  two: 'two', 
  three: 'three'
} as const;

type Slug = typeof SlugValues[keyof typeof SlugValues]

type Guide = { slug: Slug };

const guide1: Guide = { slug: "one" };
const guide2: Guide = { slug: "two" };

const guides: Guide[] = [guide1, guide2];

const arrayFromSlugs = guides.map((guide) => guide.slug);

function isSlug(value: string): value is Slug {
  return Object.values<string>(SlugValues).includes(value);
}

function getIndex(pathname: string) {
  return isSlug(pathname) ? arrayFromSlugs.indexOf(pathname) : -1;
}
```

In the above example, we can define an object using the [`const assertion`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions). From this, we can infer the `Slug` type from the object values. Then When checking if a string is a `Slug` value in the `isSlug` function, we can pass in a generic type into the `Object.values` function, allowing us to check if our value to be checked is actually one of the allowed values.